# How to add a script only for some views using Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I want to insert a script in some views like /Account and /Home. There is a way to insert the script in _Layout.cshtml but only for these views? or must I necessarily insert it in the cshtml of each view.

My project structure is like this:

```
/Views
     /Account
            /index.cshtml
            /...
     /Home
            /index.cshtml
            /...
     /Offices
            /index.cshtml
            /...
     /Reservations
            /index.cshtml
            /...
     /Shared
            /_Layout.cshtml
            /...
```

Comment: Shouldn't your script reference be built by your Bundle? Also your Layout shouldn't know about the existence of any specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

By default all the views will use the shared/_Layout.cshtml. In _Layout.cshtml we will write the common code which will use across all the pages. If you want only some pages needs the script files then remove the scripts register part in main layout file i.e shared/_Layout.cshtml and create another layout file with scripts. Then use this newly created layout file in the views where you require scripts. Remaining views(don't require scripts) still use the shared/_Layout.cshtml.

If all the views under the module either require or not require scripts then the better way would be create seperate _ViewStart.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml in every folder in you case under /Accounts and /Home. So that all the views under the Account folder will use only that folder layout views.